# Solution to needs

Tags: word-usage

Is this expression correct?

"solution to your recruitment needs"

You don't really solve ones needs, I suppose... You meet somebody's needs...

I see it being used widely but I'm not sure if it's logically correct.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, but maybe a 'fulfillment of needs' is more correct.

Comment: In marketing speak, _solution_ is a buzzword that has no meaning - or, more cynically, a way of turning everything into a problem that the produce being marketed can "solve".

Comment: This is interesting. Marketing speak obviously obscures this (probably via [solution selling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_selling)?), but it'd be nice to know if the phrase "solving a need" is a marketing-driven neologism, or a *need* could be *solved* earlier too? The ngram-viewer shows hits from the 1920s, but those may be false positives. Btw, I definitely feel a semantic difference between *solving* and *meeting* needs, so even if it's a neologism, it's a good one.

Comment: Marketing-driven neologism, I agree... thanks for your thoughts, guys!

Answer (score 1):

While it may be marketing hyperbole, it's not that hard to make sense of. If you're a business and you don't have enough employees (i.e. you need to recruit more people), that's a problem.  More specifically, you usually need to recruit the best people, and not being able to do that is a problem. They claim to be able to solve these problems you encounter in the recruiting process.

So while a need is not technically a problem, the relationship is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider:

"*meet your recruitment needs*"

Solution implies a problem exists.